# Webpack with Less and Source Map - Weird path behaviour

Tags: webpack, less, source-maps, css-loader, less-loader

I have been trying to resolve an issue for a long time with Webpack, Less and Code Map - it seems to all show the right information for everything except the styles. The issue is that all Less files are displayed with the full path of project location. How can I get it configured/resolved to show the actual relative path? 
[image]

Here's my Webpack config/sample project that gives me this output:

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './app.js',
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            app: './'
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(less)$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'less-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                    }
                }
            ],
        }]
    },
    mode: 'none'
}
```

Less file:

```
.div {
    background:blue;
}
```

app.js

```
import 'app/app.less';
```